# Set XmlType during xjc class generation

Tags: java, maven, xsd, xjc, xmltype

I'm using xjc via maven to generate sources. I'm using an XSD and a bindings file. I would like my generated classes to have the annotation @XmlType(name = ""). I can't see how to set the name to be blank.

I've tried (amongst other ideas) annotating using annox:annotate("http://annox.dev.java.net") with annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType" but this adds another @XmlType annotation rather than replacing/overwriting the existing one.

Is there a way to set the @XmlType's name to be blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` is left blank if the Type is an anonymous type. Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) (Section "Mapping a Class").

To do that, you need to declare your type inside an `<element>` tag. The following schema shows an example:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Container">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Item" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Item">
        <xs:complexType >

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Here, element `Item` is of an anonymous type, and here's the generated class:

```java
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Item")
public class Item {


}
```